# Using an AsyncTask to update a user profile image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have a problem with the user profile picture update in my android application.

**Introduction**

In my `MainActivity` I can switch between two Fragments, the first one is the `HomeFragment` and the second is the `UserProfileFragment`.
In the UserProfile, the user can decide to upload a new image, so i let the user pick the image from local storage, then i upload this picture into `FirebaseStorage` and get the download link.
I use a class called `LoadImageTask` extending an `AsyncTask` that download the image from url and then upload the resulting bitmap into an `ImageView` that i have in my `UserProfileFragment`.

**The problem:**

When a user uploads a new profile picture, `LoadImageTask` does his job correctly. The problem is that, when the user tries to update his profile picture, the `ImageView` is still showing the old image and the user must go to `HomeFragment` and then go back to the `UserProfileFragment` to see the update. So, basically the update works but the Profile Picture change is not showed immediately.

**What i tried to do**

I tried many things like invalidating the `imageView` or trying to force the `imageView` in other ways but it didn't worked.

```html
public class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView image;

    public LoadImageTask(ImageView image) {
        this. image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String downloadUrl = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(downloadUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if(result != null) {
            image.setImageBitmap(circleTransformation(result));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If there isn't any reason against it, you could use an image loading library such as [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Answer (score 0):

When you pick image from the local storage you can set image to imageView from the uri in your onActivityResult.

```
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```